# Please explain how Contact record is being updated with the Account ID when there is not any update DML

Tags: apex

This code gets executed in a "before" trigger on the Contact object and the goal of the code is to create an account record that is equal to the contact record in salesforce if the account is null when the contact record is created.

The code works, but being relatively new to apex coding, it isn't clear to me how the Contact record is being updated.

Can someone please tell me how the Contact record is being updated with the Account ID without the UPDATE DML Statement?

```
public with sharing class ContactAction {    
    public static void createAccountFromContact(list<Contact> con) {
        List<Contact> needAccounts = new List<Contact>();
        for (Contact c : con) {
            if (String.isBlank(c.accountid)) {
                needAccounts.add(c);
            }
        }
        if (needAccounts.size() > 0) {
            List<Account> newAccounts = new List<Account>();
            Map<String,Contact> contactsByNameKeys = new Map<String,Contact>();             
            //Create account for each contact
            for (Contact c : needAccounts) {
                String accountName = c.firstname + ' ' + c.lastname;
                contactsByNameKeys.put(accountName,c);
                Account a = new Account(name=accountName);
                newAccounts.add(a);
            }              
            insert newAccounts;                 
            for (Account a : newAccounts) {
                //Put account ids on contacts
                if (contactsByNameKeys.containsKey(a.Name)) {
                contactsByNameKeys.get(a.Name).accountId = a.Id; 
            }                                                               
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the trigger that is firing this function is  `onBefore Update` there is no need to do any extra DML Statements for the Contact update.

So the line where you do

```
contactsByNameKeys.get(a.Name).accountId = a.Id;
```

is good enough to update the Contact's record with the related Account ID

Answer (score 2):

Per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) for trigger context variables, trigger.new

> Returns a list of the new versions of the sObject records. Note that
>   this sObject list is only available in insert and update triggers, and
>   the records can only be modified in before triggers.

So if you modify the records in the trigger.new in before triggers it will get saved to database without any additional DML statement.

In your method, `list<Contact> con` is passed as parameter and it will be trigger.new passed from trigger to this method. So if you change any of the records in this list, it will get saved to database without any explicit DML statement. This line

```
contactsByNameKeys.get(a.Name).accountId = a.Id;
```

updates the contact record by assigning `a.Id` to the contact's `accountId`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the map "contactsByNameKeys", you are assigning the AccountId value on a contact record with newly created account record Id. So the current contact is being updated with the created Account

```
contactsByNameKeys.get(a.Name).accountId = a.Id;
```